# @AfterReturning desde una clase Aspect a otra clase Aspect

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Estoy intentando ejecutar un método después de finalizar la ejecución de otro pero **@AfterReturning** no funciona:

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* com.example.service.ExampleService.run(..)) && "
    + "args(id,..)")
@Override
public void afterRun(int id) {
  // code  after run
}
```

donde **ExampleService.run()** es:

```
@Service
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {
   @Override
   public void run(int id) {
     // code 
   }
}
```

y se llama desde la clase **ExampleAspect** a través de un método con **@AfterReturning**:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnBean(ExampleService.class)
@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect

   @Autowired
   private final ExampleService exampleService;

   @AfterReturning("execution(* com.example.service.BeforeService.before(..)) && "
      + "args(id,..)")
   public void run(int id) {
      this.exampleService.run();
   }
}
```